# Execute Multiple SQL queries in c# prepared statement

Tags: c#, mysql, prepared-statement

I was wondering if it is possible to execute multiple SQL queries in one prepared statement.
This is the first query I want to execute :

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO Table VALUES (@Date,@Manager,@Joiner,@Number,@Type,@Join,@Status)",
                    conn);
                    cmd.Prepare();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manager",Manager);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Joiner", Joiner);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", Number);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", Type);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Join", Join);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status);
                    cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

And right after I need to execute 
`DELETE FROM Table where Date='@Date'` query. 
what is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql supports batch commands. This means that after the first command text you can add a semicolon and the second command in a single string submitted via ExecuteNonQuery (do not use ExecuteReader when you don't need to read anything)

```
 "INSERT INTO Table VALUES (@Date,@Manager,@Joiner,@Number,@Type,@Join,@Status);
 DELETE FROM Table where Date=@Date"
```

Notice also that I have removed the single quotes around the @Date parameter. Leaving them will transform the parameter placeholder in a literal string. This will hardly find any rows to delete. On second thought, I am perplexed by this second command because it will delete the same record inserted in the first command.

Comment: The second command is just an example , the query I am running is different. Thank you for this answer.